# C pointer error -> expression must be a modifiable lvalue

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I am not able to set a data member of a struct object by manipulating the data members of another struct object and getting an error : expression must be a modifiable lvalue.

I have already seen all the answers to this particular error code, but couldn't get any satisfactory result.

IMAGE STRUCT IS DEFINED AS FOLLOWS:

```
typedef struct{
    int w,h,c;            
    float *data;   
}image;
```

This image struct contains the data as a pointer to a float value that contains the pixel values of a particular image.
Now the task is to change all the pixels to grayscale.
We have a criteria denoted as Y' = 0.299 R' + 0.587 G' + .114 B'.Or for every pixel value in all the 3 channels, I have to take this weighted mean.

MY FUNCTION TO CHANGE RGB VALUES TO GRAYSCALE IS THIS:

```
image rgb_to_grayscale(image im)
{
    assert(im.c == 3);
    image gray = make_image(im.w, im.h, 1);        // Creates a image struct with *data containing 
                                                   // 1 Channel

    // Creating pointers to struct
    image * ptr_gray , * ptr_im;

    // Point to the address of the struct objects
    // Gray Image
    ptr_gray = &gray; 
    float * gray_data = ptr_gray->data;
    float(*gray_data_matrix) [im.w][im.h] = gray_data;

    // Point to the address of the struct objects
    // Given Image
    ptr_im = &im; 
    float * im_data = ptr_im->data;
    float(*im_data_matrix) [im.w][im.h] = im_data;

    // Now we have the weighted mean like:
    //Y' = 0.299 R' + 0.587 G' + .114 B'

    // So for a given *data I have to calculate the value over the whole 3-D Matrix

    float red_matrix[im.h][im.w];
    float green_matrix[im.h][im.w];
    float blue_matrix[im.h][im.w];

    int k =0;
    for(int i= 0; i< im.h ; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < im.w ; j++){
            while(k<im.c)){
                if(k == 0){
                    red_matrix[i][j] = *(*(*(im_data_matrix +k) + i) + j)*0.299 ;
                }
                if(k == 1){
                    green_matrix[i][j] =   *(*(*(im_data_matrix +k) + i) + j)*0.587;
                }
                if(k == 2){
                    blue_matrix[i][j] = *(*(*(im_data_matrix +k) + i) + j)*0.114;
                }

            }
            *(*(gray_data_matrix+i)+j) = *(*(red_matrix + i)+j) + 
                                            *(*(green_matrix + i)+j) + 
                                                *(*(blue_matrix + i)+j);
    k++;
        }

    }

    return gray;
}
```

This line throws error ::

```
*(*(gray_data_matrix+j)+i) = *(*(red_matrix + i)+j) + 
                                            *(*(green_matrix + i)+j) + 
                                                *(*(blue_matrix + i)+j);
```

The error is : expression must be a modifiable lvalue.
How to resolve this error??

Comment: You could simplify this a lot by using [], gray_data_matrix[j][i] = red_matrix[i][j] + green_matrix[i][j] + blue_matrix[i][j];  Also in your loop, im_data_matrix[k][i][j], why are you using floating point values for RGB?  typically RGB is made up of 3 x 8 bit bytes.  An RGB can then be stored in a long integer, 24 bits.

Comment: You have to zero variable `k` in each loop start. In your case, while loop will be executed only one full iteration.

Comment: Providing a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) helps finding the error as the readers don't need to dig through unrelated code. All the calculation of grey value and all the loops are not related to a compiler error about type of an expression. The process of creating a MCVE can also make the problem more clear to yourself.

Comment: You don't really need `red_matrix`, `green_matrix` and `blue_matrix` as 2-D arrays as you only process one pixel at a time. Simple scalar variables will do.

Comment: The line `float(*gray_data_matrix) [im.w][im.h] = gray_data;` does not compile. What is this supposed to do ?

Comment: You define `gray_data_matrix` and `im_data_matrix` with same type. Yet you use an extra level of dereferencing for `im_data_matrix`. You should get your types sorted out.

Comment: Your `im_data_matrix` variable is one dimension too large. It should be something like `float (*gray_data_matrix)[im.w] = (void *)gray_data;` (The type cast to `(void *)` avoids a warning. You could type cast to `(float (*)[im.w])` instead.)

Comment: @SPlatten Yup I did this. As far as float value of data is concerned, it's defined in the MOOC like this.No idea why the instructor did this. I think stb_image library defines image like this.

Comment: @GuillaumePetitjean I am using g++, it compiles for me. The whole code is here: https://github.com/jalotra/vision-hw0/blob/master/src/process_image.c

Comment: @Gerhardh Since this code builds upon stb_image library, that's why I thought nobody would like to setup a env to reproduce the error.

Comment: @IanAbbott Yup I did what you said and that improved the space complexity a lot. And I changed this expression *(*(gray_data_matrix+j)+i) to gray_matrix[i][j] and it worked. But I couldn't comprehend what changed? Plus I am getting a segmentation error after running the loop for channel == 0 ; and the segmentation fault occurs some pixels before the limit im.h. Can you please help me debugging the error. https://pastebin.com/ns13Sru8. The source code is here : https://github.com/jalotra/vision-hw0/blob/master/src/process_image.c

Comment: The segmentation fault in https://github.com/jalotra/vision-hw0/blob/master/src/process_image.c is likely due to operator precedence. Instead of `*gray_data_matrix[width][height]`, use `(*gray_data_matrix)[width][height]` or `gray_data_matrix[0][width][height]`.

Comment: @IanAbbott Thanks my bad. I am not good with pointers.Can you suggest me any resource to get better with pointers?

Comment: The key things are: (1) postfix operators such as array subscripting `[]` have higher precedence than unary operators such as `*` (dereference); (2) an array in an expression usually decays into a pointer to its first element (except when the array is the operand of `sizeof` or `_Alignof`); (3) `((a)[x])` is equivalent to `(*((a) + (x)))`. Also see [Arrays and Pointers](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html) in the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, the problem is in the data structures you are using. In particular the definition of the variable `gray_data_matrix` in `float(*gray_data_matrix) [im.w][im.h] = gray_data;`. It doesn't compile with standard gcc and I don't understand what you are trying to define here.

You could simply travel the RGB image `im.data` pixels and at each iteration proceed to your weighted average computation.

Something like this (I didn't test !):

```
for(int i= 0; i< im.h ; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < im.w ; j++){
               gray.data[i][j] =   im.data[0][i][j]*0.299 
                                 + im.data[1][i][j]* xxx
                                 + im.data[2][i][j]* xxx;
        }
}
```